# Can't get delphi SQL LIKE to work with %

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm doing a school project and need to code a query to filter a dataset to certain variables. All my SQL works fine, except I can't get the LIKE statement to work with %-signs. I believe my syntax is wrong. Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

The code:

```
qryMovie.SQL.Clear;
qryMovie.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Movies');
qryMovie.SQL.Add('WHERE Genre =  ' + QuotedStr(genre));
qryMovie.SQL.Add('AND Price BETWEEN ' + minPrice + ' AND ' + maxPrice);
qryMovie.SQL.Add('AND Title LIKE %' + title + '%');
qryMovie.Open;
```

Error produced:

'Syntax error in query expression 'Genre =  'Action/Adventure'
AND Price BETWEEN 0 AND 200
AND Title LIKE %Star Wars%''

Comment: Better use parameters.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/delphi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> LIKE %Star Wars%

but you need

> LIKE '%Star Wars%'

You need to quote `%` with  `'`:

```
qryMovie.SQL.Add(' AND Title LIKE ''%' + title + '%''');
```

Anyway you should use binded parameters instead of concatenating SQL string. It is error-prone and could lead to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I use your code i receive the error  "Expected ( but received the string literal " + title + ".

Comment: Single quotes need to be doubled-up when embedded in a Pascal string.

Comment: Even better - use parameters. It is faster, easier to read and not prone to SQL injection errors, and can handle O'Carrolls and O'Connors of this world. If you can't use params, you should use `''%'' + QuotedStr(title) + '%'''`